# My website won't resolve on my browser!

Tags: website, web, http

I own a website (shared hosting with a hosting service).  When I try to open the website my browser won't/can't open it.  In IE it says "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

I contacted my hosting company and they tell me the server is up.  When I try to ping the site from my machine it says:

> Ping request could not find host godsurfer.com. Please check the name
>   and try again.

When I use an online ping service it does find the server.

My hosting company suggested that I flush the DNS.  I did that and still no site.  Then I rebooted my computer, rebooted my router and even unplugged my cable modem (and plugged it back in) but still no site.

My hosting company is saying it is my ISP or my machine.  I was able to view the site as of an hour ago.

Does anyone have any tips that I can try so I can view my site?

`tracert`:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Jeff>ping godsurfer.com
Ping request could not find host godsurfer.com. Please check the name and try ag
ain.

C:\Users\Jeff>tracert 184.172.180.195

Tracing route to 184.172.180.195-static.reverse.softlayer.com [184.172.180.195]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

      9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     10    44 ms    28 ms    27 ms  e5-1-40G.ar6.LAX1.gblx.net [67.17.111.65]
     11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     12    78 ms     *       39 ms  e5-1-40G.ar6.LAX1.gblx.net [67.17.111.65]
     13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     14    38 ms    30 ms    28 ms  e5-1-40G.ar6.LAX1.gblx.net [67.17.111.65]
     15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     16    43 ms    27 ms    31 ms  e5-1-40G.ar6.LAX1.gblx.net [67.17.111.65]
     17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     18    39 ms    28 ms     *     e5-1-40G.ar6.LAX1.gblx.net [67.17.111.65]
     19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     20    51 ms    44 ms     *     e5-1-40G.ar6.LAX1.gblx.net [67.17.111.65]
     21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     22    39 ms    35 ms    51 ms  e5-1-40G.ar6.LAX1.gblx.net [67.17.111.65]
     23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     24    44 ms    35 ms    42 ms  e5-1-40G.ar6.LAX1.gblx.net [67.17.111.65]
     25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     26    43 ms    33 ms    44 ms  e5-1-40G.ar6.LAX1.gblx.net [67.17.111.65]
     27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     28    40 ms    29 ms    29 ms  e5-1-40G.ar6.LAX1.gblx.net [67.17.111.65]
     29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     30    47 ms    47 ms     *     e5-1-40G.ar6.LAX1.gblx.net [67.17.111.65]



**tracert godsurfer.com**

    Unable to resolve target system name godsurfer.com.
```

`ipconfig /all`:

```
       DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 209.18.47.61
                                           209.18.47.62

    IP Address: 76.167.185.52
```

Comment: One more question, if you go to whatismyip.com is your IP the same as that 67.17.111.65? That tracert basically says it is not your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, thank you for posting the actual site name. It makes this a lot easier.

I suspect that it may not even be in your system, but just a problem somewhere along the route. So let's test that.

Open a Command Prompt and type in `tracert 184.172.180.195` Then post back the results. That is your IP address.

Then do `tracert godsurfer.com` and post back the results.

Also, do an `ipconfig /all` and tell me what your DNS servers are please.

I also assume that when you go to Tools>Internet Options>Connections>LAN Settings there is no proxy server configured, and that you can get to other sites with no problems.

I also would be thinking about checking the HOSTS (no extension, open with notepad) file here: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

See if there are any entries related to your site, and if so put a # in front of them.

After seeing the tracert/traceroute, it was clear that the problem was just a router along the way. They are probably already working on it, but if it does not resolve itself within a day, call your ISP and tell them that while while trying to trace to that IP, you are bombing out at e5-1-40G.ar6.LAX1.gblx.net [67.17.111.65], and ask them if they can let the owner of the router they have a problem.

Comment: P.S. I was able to get to your site with no problems.

Comment: is any of the information you are asking me to post going to include sensitive information to my machine?

Comment: @Jeff V:  Your public IP address is basically known by every web site you visit (the web sites have to know or else they can't respond to your computer's requests).  There are many people who wish not to share their public IP address in web-based forums though, for fear of dark hacking attempts against their machines.  If you're behind a firewall (e.g., a LinkSys broadband router, or something similar), then you're probably safe assuming that none of your ports are open.  There's a free service by Steve Gibson that will help you test your firewall:  https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's a problem with your regional network, or perhaps a bad routing entry.  I've seen this once or twice, and it usually seems to rectify itself after an hour or two.  Not sure who you'd contact if it persists.

Answer (score 1):

@Jeff V: Your site does resolve correctly for me here on a Comcast connection, and your screenshot shows a routing error inside the Global Crossing data center at Los Angeles - nothing you can do about that other than wait for the network gurus to fix it.

Try using this site next time you have a question about your site's availability: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/godsurfer.com

Hope that helps,
Isaac

Answer (score 1):

While its not a solution to the problem itself, you can probably use [tor](http://www.torproject.org/) or some other proxy - i used to run my own on a VPS - to check if its up. I've had a similar problem with one of the ISPs i use, and a web comic i read, and it takes a while to clear up sometimes.